# problems with configuration of mathjax 3 demo interactive TeX input and HTML output

Tags: config, interactive, mathjax, sign

demo path:
https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-demos-web/blob/master/input-tex2chtml.html

I add mathjax config:

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script>
    MathJax = {
        tex: {
            inlineMath: [['$', '$']]
        }
    };
</script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js"></script>
```

run like this:
[image: MathJax v3:TeX to HTML]

The `$` sign should not be there, but it still shows，even though the Tex grammar is right.

How do I make the `$` go away? Where am I wrong? and what's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is correct. There is a slight issue with the way you are trying to use the input field and `tex2chtmlPromise` via `convert`.

You can see that your code is working if you put your lines in the body rather than in the textarea:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>MathJax v3 with interactive TeX input and HTML output</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
    <script>
        MathJax = {
            tex: {
                inlineMath: [["$", "$"]]
            }
        };
    </script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
Testing math:
<p>$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}$</p>
</body>

</html>
```

---

For more information about your usage issue, see this GitHub Issue [Delimiter not working with MathJax.tex2chtmlPromise method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear)

> "the MathJax.tex2chtmlPromise() function takes a LaTeX string as its parameter, which does not require a delimiter. [...] So if you are passing delimiters to this, they will be typeset as part of the math. There is no need for delimiters because you are identifying the math, not MathJax, and are passing it directly to the function. There is no need for delimiters, because there is no need to separate the math from the surrounding text, as you have already done that yourself."

When you use the `$` delimiter in your document, your specified delimiters will be handled appropriately. The delimiters are necessary in the document body as a way to distinguish it from the surrounding text.

However, in the textarea, it is expected that the only thing the user inputs is valid Math. Given this expectation, delimiters are unexpected. When the raw input is passed to the `MathJax.tex2chtmlPromise` *any* text included will be typeset as math. Hence, why your $ signs appear as literals in your output field.